# d3 I can't add nodes

Tags: tree, d3.js, addition

I have a tree and I'd like to click on a node and add another.

But I can't. Where can I get more knowledge from tree layout?

```
    var root = {"name": "A", "info": "tst", "children": [                 
        ......
        ]};

    var nodes = tree(root), links , diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal();

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg").....

    var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")                   
              ....
            .on("click", function(d) {
        //try add one node in this node. for example {"name":"asdf"};


    }) ;

    node.append("text").attr("id", function(d) {
   .....
    });

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
         ....
    });

     links = tree.links(nodes);

    .....
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

See

[D3 API - TreeLayout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#wiki-tree)

to understand how the data has to be setup to be understood by the tree layout. Basically children are hold as an array in an attribute named "children" in the parent data etc